# JPA entity classes residing in a Wildfly module are not scanned

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have some JPA entity classes residing in a Wildfly module. Although there are entity classes in this module, there's no JPA deployment descriptor (persistence.xml file) in the module. Here's the complete path of the module:

```
{Wildfly_installation}/modules/system/layers/base/br/edu/ufca/main/ufca.jar
```

The module descriptor (located in the same folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="br.edu.ufca">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ufca.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Now I have a web application where I declare the dependency on this module in META-INF\MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: 
Dependencies: br.edu.ufca export
```

I also have, in the web application, the persistence.xml file where I list some entity classes that are located in the ufca.jar module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="criacao-email">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CriacaoEmailDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>br.edu.ufca.modelo.Setor</class>
        <!-- more classes -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The problem is that when I run the web application executing code that tries to load some entity classes using an EntityManager, for example, I get exceptions like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Setor is not mapped [SELECT s FROM Setor s ORDER BY s.nome]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:443) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:401) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:42) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$911040993$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.createQuery(Unknown Source) [hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:]
    at br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.negocio.CriadorEmailSetorial.localizarSetores(CriadorEmailSetorial.java:28) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 122 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Setor is not mapped [SELECT s FROM Setor s ORDER BY s.nome]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 168 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Setor is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 176 more
```

which clearly shows that the JPA provider didn't scan the entity classes. But if I access from the web application any class from the Wildfly module without using JPA, I have success, which shows that the module is really in the classpath of the application.

Is this default behaviour or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Marcos

Answer (score 0):

Modules defined in the module directory are not part of the deployment and therefore not scanned. If you need your entities to be scanned they need to be included in your deployment.

Comment: Not that I know of. I haven't tested, but it might work if you listed the entities in the persistence.xml. I'm not sure if module dependencies would be added before that phase or not though.

Comment: You can see in my question that I listed the entity classes in the persistence.xml from the start. It didn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess there probably isn't a way then. You'll have to include it in your deployment.