# JPA Entities as module in wildfly shared across webapp and EJB deployments

Tags: jpa, jboss, wildfly

I'm required to separate a project into several maven projects and deploy it in a WildFly server. This is the requested organization:

- `com.mycompany.entity`: This project contains JPA Annotated POJOs. It is a single jar (not ejb or war) registered as [Wildfly module](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)
- `com.mycompany.dataservice`: Just a bunch of DAO interfaces, Again single jar registered as a Wildfly module. Depends on  `com.mycompany.entity`
- `com.mycompany.dataserviceImpl`: An EJB app that implements DAO interfaces and registers JNDI resources. Depends on  `com.mycompany.entity` and `com.mycompany.dataservice`
- `com.mycompany.web`: A web app that injects EJB through JNDI names. Depends on  `com.mycompany.entity` and `com.mycompany.dataservice`

I have the `persistence.xml` file in the `com.mycompany.dataserviceImpl` project with hibernate-entitymanager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mycompanyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mycompany.entity.MyEntity</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So far, I have registered `com.mycompany.entity` and `com.mycompany.dataservice` modules in the wildfly server. Also, I have deployed both `com.mycompany.dataserviceImpl` and `com.mycompany.web` applications.

But when browsing the webapp, it throws: `javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.mycompany.entity.MyEntity`.

Is this kind of separation possible?. Everything worked when there were only two projects (EJB and Web).

Comment: Did you try add "<jar-file>" tag instead of "<class>" on persistence-unit?

Comment: @SevanNerse the `entity.jar` is not embedded in the `dataserviceImpl.jar`, but in  the `modules` directory of the WildFly server. So I don't have the path to the file.

Comment: did you add the module dependency in your webapp? I mean adding com.mycompany.dataservice in your com.mycompany.web manifest.mf

Comment: Yes I did it. I also created a simple WS inside the `dataserviceImpl` project in order to isolate the error and it persists. I'm afraid this is close related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404069. Entities defined in a WildFly modules are not scanned.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not packaging your application in an EAR file?

Comment: It's a technical requirement from client. They argued that having core libraries (e.g. entities) as shared modules would avoid to have different versions of the same library for different applications.